# SQL syntax for select a column insert into an existing column from another table

Tags: sql, select, insert

How to select a column insert into an existing column from another table in sql?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question - it's unclear at the moment whether you want to insert a value into one table which has been selected from another table, or something else entirely.

Comment: You should really elaborate on your actual problem. And if the syntax for this particular scenario was your problem, you should just *google*!!

Answer (score 2):

Query is mysql

```
insert into existing_table (column_name) select column_name from another_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
insert into table1 (column) 
values (select column from table2 where condition)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the *schema* of both the columns should be  the same, i.e. if the column from which you are trying to copy the values contain DateTime values, the target column too should accept DateTime values.

Then the answer would simply be:

```
insert into targetTable (targetColumn) values ( select sourceColumn from sourceTable where predicate )
```

Comment: In that case you can always mark it as the answer